# How to find the XPATH for the below code having ==$0

Tags: selenium-webdriver, robotframework, xpath-2.0

How to find the XPATH for the below code having ==$0

[HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uo7LD.png)

I want to validate the number "1504873879" at the end of the tags.

```
<font style="FONT-SIZE:14px">Flat 101<font face="Mary Ann"><font style="FONT-SIZE:14px"><font face="Mary Ann"><font style="FONT-SIZE:14px">&nbsp;</font></font></font></font><font face="Mary Ann"><font style="FONT-SIZE:14px"><font face="Mary Ann"><font style="FONT-SIZE:14px">&nbsp;</font></font></font></font>Trinity Square 23-59<font face="Mary Ann"><font style="FONT-SIZE:14px"><font face="Mary Ann"><font style="FONT-SIZE:14px">&nbsp;</font></font></font></font><br>
Staines Road<font face="Mary Ann"><font style="FONT-SIZE:14px"><font face="Mary Ann"><font style="FONT-SIZE:14px">&nbsp;</font></font></font></font><br>
Hounslow<font face="Mary Ann"><font style="FONT-SIZE:14px"><font face="Mary Ann"><font style="FONT-SIZE:14px">&nbsp;</font></font></font></font><br>
TW3 3GE<font face="Mary Ann" xpath="1"><font style="FONT-SIZE:14px"><font face="Mary Ann"> </font><br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<font face="Mary Ann"><font style="FONT-SIZE:14px">Order number:</font></font><strong><font face="Mary Ann"><font style="FONT-SIZE:14px">&nbsp;</font></font></strong></font></font>1504873879<font face="Mary Ann"><font style="FONT-SIZE:14px"><strong>&nbsp;</strong><br>
Order date:

    13/09/2021

</font></font>&nbsp;<br>
<br>
```

Comment: You don't show enough HTML to see what is the tag containing that text.

Comment: I have updated the HTML, please let me know if it helps!

Comment: You haven't showed what you've tried. You need to put in a little bit of effort before asking. Also, you haven't shown enough useful HTML. Is this data inside of a span or div tag? Is it part of a form? How do you plan to distinguish this small section of  HTML from all of the other HTML? Are you just wanting to validate any text after the text "Order number:"?

Comment: Do **not** post code as image. Rather use a code section. This is part of creating a [mcve].

Comment: //font[text()='Order number:']/parent::font/parent::font/parent::font and then use get text method. Might not be the best xpath. You need to ask your dev to make a better UI which has better locators.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplified Xpath:

```
//font[text()='Order number:']//ancestor::font[text()='1504873879']
```

Answer (score 0):

The following XPATH has worked:

```
//font[text()='Order number:']/parent::font/parent::font/parent::font/parent::font[text()='6591357359']
```